# OKTA: Authorization code flow without PKCE for angular 7 application

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect, okta

How to migrate existing angular 7 application from implicit flow to Authorization code flow.
Note: Without pkce.

Actual:
In existing uses the IDP/Single sing on mechanism to login automatically to the application.

Expectation:
I want to change from implicit flow and use only **Authorization code flow without pkce** and have to same automatically login (IDP/ SSO)

Backend using spring boot micro service, already done the okta provide and consumer API.

I don't see any same implementation or sample application atleast for Authorization code flow alone.

Thanks in advance

Please let me know if any additional information is need or not clear with the info I have provided above.

Answer (score 0):

Using a "public" client without PKCE is very unsafe and Angular apps can only be public OAuth2 clients.

Actually, [according to latest recommendations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390), your Angular app should not be an OAuth2 client at all (it should not fetch tokens from the authorization server). The best alternative is probably to have its requests authorized with sessions on a BFF running on your server.

The good news are:

- by default, Spring confidential OAuth2 client don't use PKCE
- as BFF, you can use a `spring-cloud-gateway` instance configured as OAuth2 client (with `oauth2Login`) and the `TokenRelay` filter between your Angular app and your resource servers (Spring stateless REST APIs secured with tokens). I wrote [a tutorial for that on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2)